# Why does the SendKeys Method delete the sign '+'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sendkeys

So I should send a barcode, which include the sign +.
The problem is that this sign don't appear on the application and delete the next number with.

I should send this for example:

> DB2+555000-04+329000-01+378000+0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000T2L0RE9WM0K6FJM0Q1X5DFRA

And I become this:

> DB255000-0429000-0178000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000T2L0RE9WM0K6FJM0Q1X5DFRA

As you can see the + sign disappear between the application and Visual Studio, because the + sign is take as SHIFT.
How can I write the '+' sign in Code, so that it is taken as + and not as SHIFT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx):

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({}).

So you should send "01{+}378000{+}..."

Comment: When I saw that you answered this question, I deleted mine without even thinking what the difference was.